# Get details of Kubernentes + Flux workload error?

Tags: kubernetes, flux

When I use `fluxctl list-workloads`, I can see that there is an error with one of my workloads:

```
fluxctl list-workloads
WORKLOAD                     CONTAINER       IMAGE                               RELEASE   POLICY
default:deployment/my-app    some-container  gcr.io/my-app/my-app:<commit hash>  error
default:helmrelease/myapp    chart-image     gcr.io/my-app/my-app:<commit hash>  DEPLOYED  automated
```

How can I see the details of that error?

Answer (score 0):

You can using blew command found the helmrelease resource

```
kubectl get helmrelease --all-namespaces
```

And using

`kubectl describe helmrelease <helmrelease> -n <ns>`

for detail message